# handleMessage(* msg) doesn't work in OMNET++

Tags: c++, omnet++

I have a wireless network consisting of 7 sensors named node1 to 7, and a gateway. each node and also gateway has an inport which is marked by @directIo. The flow of data is in the way that, the gateway chooses one of the nodes as the cluster head and send a message containing the id number of the chosen cluster head to the nodes using sendDirect(), the problem is that, the node's handleMessage() event isn't called at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>


using namespace omnetpp;

class node : public cSimpleModule
{
private:
    float propagationDelay;
    float duration;
    double eLevel;
    float dist;
    int mCount;
    int clusterHead;
    cModule *target;
    cMessage *timerMessage;
    cMessage *pack;
    cMessage *weak;
    cMessage *msg;
    bool gReq;
  protected:
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};

Define_Module(node);

void node::initialize()
{
    gReq=false;
    eLevel=par("energyLeve");
    mCount=0;
    dist=(rand()%3)+1;
    timerMessage = new cMessage("timer");
    /*if (par("sendMsgOnInit").boolValue() == true) {
       EV << getName()<<getIndex() << "------ distance: " << dist << "\n";
    }*/
}

void node::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    if (msg->getSenderModuleId()==2){
            clusterHead=atoi((char *) msg->getName());
            if (getId()!=clusterHead){
                pack= new cMessage("Hello");
                timerMessage =new cMessage("Timer");
                mCount=0;
                target = getSimulation()->getModule(clusterHead);
                sendDirect(pack, propagationDelay, duration, target, "radioIn");
                eLevel-=dist;
                if (eLevel<50 && gReq==false){
                    weak= new cMessage("w");
                    target = getSimulation()->getModule(2);
                    sendDirect(weak, propagationDelay, duration, target, "radioIn");
                    gReq=true;
                    EV << "node index: "<< getIndex() << "request sent!";
                }
                EV << getName()<<getIndex() << "------ eLevel: " << eLevel;
                scheduleAt(simTime()+0.1, timerMessage);
            }
        }

}
```

Code 2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>
using namespace omnetpp;


class gateway : public cSimpleModule
{
  public:
    int mCount;
    cMessage *clusterNodeSelecMess;
    cMessage *timerMessage;
    cMessage *msg;
    int round;
    int clusterHeadId;
    bool weakNodes[7];
    int inx;
  protected:
    int clusterHeadSelection(bool weakNodes[7]);
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};
Define_Module(gateway);

void gateway::initialize()
{
    msg= new cMessage("self");
    scheduleAt(0.0, msg);
    round =0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
            weakNodes[i]=false;
        }
}

void gateway::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    if(msg->getSenderModuleId()==2){
        round++;
        clusterHeadId=clusterHeadSelection(weakNodes);
        std::string s = std::to_string(clusterHeadId);
        EV << "Node number "<<clusterHeadId << " selected as CH\n";
        char const *pchar = s.c_str();
        clusterNodeSelecMess = new cMessage(pchar);
            for (cModule::SubmoduleIterator it(getModuleByPath("FTN")); !it.end(); ++it) {
                    cModule *temp = *it;
                    if (strcmp(temp->getName(),getName())!=0){
                        sendDirect(clusterNodeSelecMess->dup(), temp, "radioIn");
                    }
                }
    }
    else if(msg->getSenderModuleId()==clusterHeadId){
        clusterHeadId=clusterHeadSelection(weakNodes);
        std::string s = std::to_string(clusterHeadId);
        EV << "Node number "<<clusterHeadId << " selected as CH\n";
        char const *pchar = s.c_str();
        clusterNodeSelecMess = new cMessage(pchar);
        for (cModule::SubmoduleIterator it(getModuleByPath("FTN")); !it.end(); ++it) {
            cModule *temp = *it;
            sendDirect(clusterNodeSelecMess->dup(), temp, "radioIn");
         }
    }
    else{
        EV << "Received from node: "<< msg->getSenderGateId() - 1 << "\n";
    }
}

int clusterHeadSelection(bool weakNodes[7]){
        int i = 0;
        int clusterHeadId;
        while(weakNodes[clusterHeadId=(rand() % 12)-2]==true){
                    i++;
                    if (i>7){
                        return(NULL);
                    }
                }
        return(clusterHeadId);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `handleMessage()` method is never called by the simulator because you never send a message to any of your modules so there is nothing to deliver. Note that `sendDirect()` calls are only present in your `handleMessage()` methods, so until one of them is called, there will be no messages to deliver. The way a simulation should work is that SOME code MUST create messages or events (e.g. timers) in the `initialize()` methods because that is the method that is called on the simulation start.

In `node::initialize()` you create a `timerMessage` but never schedule it so it is not delivered to `handleMessage()`. (not that it would help because the `handleMessage()` code would explicitly ignore it):

The `gateway` module creates and schedules a self message, and that is delivered to the `gateway::handleMessage()` but it's not handled and most likely falls through to the `else` case at the end and then just does nothing.

Comment: Thank you @Rudi, as far as it is a revised version of another project there are some elements in the project that hasn't been used yet. but gateway has a scheduled message in `gateway::initialize()` and it successfully sends messages to each node in the `gateway::handleMessage()`, the problem is the `node::handleMessage()` never gets called although each of them receives a message from the gateway and you can see in in the simulation. I had the doubt that to handle the messages which have been sent via `sendDirect()` method I should use another event like `apply()` ....

Comment: The problem is Solved.